# HTML Email - Font Resizing on Gmail App for Mobiles

Tags: android, html, email, gmail, html-email

I have an issue with an HTML Email I've developed for a client. They're all using Gmail on Android phones to test and preview what's being sent and also GSuite. The problem I'm having (font being shrunk) is happening in both, but not in my Litmus tests, just when they preview it through iContact for Salesforce.

So where I've declared larger headings it's showing as about font-size 12 pixels (I'm judging that by eye based on their screenshots)... not the 26 pixels it's set to be. The other text blocks are fine, however, and show at the correct size (16 pixels). Example:

```html
    <tr>
     <td class="container-padding" align="left" style="padding-left: 40px; 
     padding-right: 40px;">
        <span class="medium-text" style="color: #333333; font-size: 16px; 
        line-height: 24px; display: block; font-family: 'Calibri', 
        Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: left; font-weight: 
        normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Aliquam maximus felis ex, eu auctor lectus pellentesque finibus. 
        Integer vel interdum felis.</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

I suppose my question is, is the issue that Gmail is forcing my `font-size: 26px` to be `font-size: 12px`. There's another example where the main email heading is even larger - 32 pixels - and that's also being shrunk.

HTML below.

```html
    <tr>
    <td class="container-padding" align="left" style="padding-left: 40px; 
    padding-right: 40px;">
        <span class="large-text" style="color: #333333; font-size: 26px; 
        line-height: 32px; display: block; font-family: 'Calibri', 
        Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: left; font-weight 
        normal;">I'm a Title that's been shrunk!</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: It seems either your gmail is forcing desktop version, which is your email just zoomed out, or you are using media queries that are affecting it. Please paste full code so your issue can be tested.

Comment: Thanks Stefano for having a look at the question!

It actually turns out it was a problem with Salesforce being really sensitive with how I'd done the HTML on titles.

So when I tested in Campaign Monitor it was fine, as I think Campaign Monitor is quite forgiving when it puts your HTML inline.

Comment: Dont think CM is forgiving, its not changing your html. Salesforce on the other hand might be trying to make your HTML compliant with standards and ends up breaking bits of it.